# How to set connection affinity mask in SQL server 2005 when enabling VIA protocol

Tags: ios, sql-server-2005, windows-7-x64, affinity, sup

I have developed an SUP HWC application(for iOS) to fetch data from SQL server 2005 using stored procedure.In SUP workstation, I'm able to see the preview while creating MBO.I deployed my application in Sybase control center and able to view the application.Till now every thing works fine :)

When I'm fetching data from the iPhone simulator, got following error:

```
error code 503 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception the tcp/ip connection to host failed
```

I'm trying clear error by fallowing this:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd5bb6c2-a4d9-4071-b2e6-a6c83970b212/commicrosoftsqlserverjdbcsqlserverexception-the-tcpip-connection-to-the-host-has-failed

Where, its saying to enable VIA protocol.I enabled it and restarted the SQL server service...
And got following error:

```
The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.
```

I'm trying to solve this by following link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955768

where, in Method-2 point no-7 it says like this:

```
Right-click VIA, and then click Properties. In the Listen Info box, type a connection affinity mask that matches the configuration of the computer, and then click OK.
```

**My problem is, How do i find connection affinity mask in configuration of a computer.**

Here is MY system details:

```
1. i7 Processor(having 8 processors) with 64 bit win7 OS.
2. My iPhone emulator is running on virtual MAC(on point-1).
```

Please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.The **service is started for me by making connection affinity mask as [0xAA]** in the setting. :)
But, still I'm not able to access my SQL server Database from iPhone HWC application(made by SUP tool) and getting same error:

"error code 503 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception the tcp/ip connection to host failed" :(

Any clue??